# Is it possible to upgrade to 20.04 LTS (Distribution Release) by first upgrading to 20.04 (development release) and then to 20.04 LTS from 19.10?

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates, 19.10, 20.04

I'm currently using Ubuntu 19.10 (installed from ISO File).

Even after 3 Days of the official release of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, `update-manager -c` is unable to fetch the distribution release of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

However, `update-manager -c -d` can fetch the development release of 20.04.

Hence, I thought of upgrading to 20.04 Development Branch and then to 20.04 LTS Distribution Release. Is it possible to do so?

**Some Thoughts**:
*On visiting various forums, I could read, that the update from 19.10 will take around 48 hours to reflect.
If anyone is able to upgrade to 20.04 LTS, could you please tell me the server through which the upgrade was done?*

Comment: Actually, the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/FocalFossa/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_18.04_LTS_or_19.10) upgrade instructions tell you to run `update-manager -c -d`.

Comment: @mikewhatever, Yes, I agree, but to my knowledge `-d` flag forces Ubuntu to search for development releases only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`do-upgrade-release -d` Works for me. The development phase is over now that its released.

Comment: Yeah. I upgraded the same way and instead of development release, LTS (Distribution Release) is installed.